# Assign policy using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to assign a policy under management group level for a contributor role using ARM template. As per Microsoft document, a contributor can create/move/delete resources, but cannot assign policies.

Regards,
Sajith

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) , A Contributor cannot perform every operation which can be performed as a owner . As you can see in the below image the contributor has 2 `Microsoft.Authorization` permissions in `NotActions` as well i.e. delete and write.

[image]

**Solution:**

You can assign [`Resource Policy Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#resource-policy-contributor) or [`Security Admin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#security-admin) Role with the contributor access that you have to create or manage Policy assignments.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you mean to say that a contributor can assign policy? As per your screenshot, a contributor cannot  Delete roles, policy assignments, policy definitions and policy set definitions

Comment: yes you are correct , you cannot set.

Comment: @Sajith, Please find the solution part in the answer